# Unexpected argument executing cmdexec on a SQL job to export to CSV

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd

I try to run this on a SQL job:

```
sqlcmd -S . -d CI_Reports -E -s"," -W -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Table]" > D:\Test.csv
```

How can I fix this error?

> Sqlcmd: '> D:\Test.csv': Unexpected argument.

Comment: Have you tried using task scheduler instead? SQL Server agent probably isn't the best place for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried like this -

```
sqlcmd -S . -d CI_Reports -E -s"," -W -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Table]" -o D:\Test.csv
```

where `-o output_file` which would identify the file that receives output from sqlcmd.

Additionally you could try `BCP` which is best suited for bulk coping data between an instance of Microsoft SQL Server and a data file in a user-specified format.
Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017).